# jQuery add totals of variables

Tags: jquery, variables, addition

This one's just weird to me. Some little syntax error or something. Simply adding the value of two variables and appending them to a third.

```
var total = 0;

input.each(function(){

    var thiis = $(this),
        cost  = thiis.attr('data-cost');

    if (thiis.prop('checked')){

        total = total + cost;
    } else {

        total = total - cost;
    }
}
```

So if `cost = 5` and the input is `checked` then `total` equal 5. Instead, I'm getting `05`.

---

Update:

Word is that the values arn't integers, so they're appending. Instead of having to do some fancy string-integer flip, is there a way for me to grab the data attribute as an integer from the get-go?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure you don't have `total = '5'` or something similar? If one is a string it'll concat instead of add.

Comment: Returns 10 here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gNZh9/

Comment: just use the `.data()` method instead of `.attr()` - `.data()` makes every attempt to properly typecast the value, whereas `.attr()` returns just a string. Also, you would only need to do `.data('cost')` instead of `.attr('data-cost')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need an integer cast if somewhere these vars are casted as strings, which is the reason for the incorect result.

and you could do just `total += parseInt(each);`

Answer (score 0):

One (or both) of the values have to have been assigned as a string. If you're seeing this a lot you can avoid it by (forcefully) casting to a number:

```
function add(){
  var total = 0;
  for (var a = 0; a < arguments.length; a++){
    var n = new Number(arguments[a]);
    //console.log(arguments[a] + '=' + n);
    if (isNaN(n)){
      throw "Argument " + a + " is not a number.";
    }
    total += n;
  }
  return total;
}

add('1', 2, 3.5);
```

It's a work-around to the real issue (if these are in-fact numbers you need to see why it is they're strings) but this will get you your intended result:

```
total = add(total,each);
```

Comment: thank you for the thorough answer.. went with reflectives because it's an existing method

Comment: @technopeasant: Using `new Number()` is also "Existing". (It's what every number derives from). Keep in mind though that `parseInt` is only good for whole numbers. If your numbers will ever have decimals you'll need to use `parseFloat`. And, this will never matter if at any time `total` is a string.